# Flex and AIR: Open and Close Window Without Re-creating

Tags: apache-flex, air

I would like to open and close a window in Flex(AIR).  I would really like to do something like:

```
var myWindow:Window = new Window();
myWindow.open(true); // open after creating(this works)

myWindow.close(); // now hide the window

myWindow.open(true);// reappear(this doesn't work after a close)
```

I'm probably missing something simple, perhaps `close()` is not what should be used.

The main thing is I want to create a window once, and then show and hide it as necessary.

EDIT: removed unnecessary vars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be it's a copy paste error, but `var` is required only in the first line. Instead of closing the window, set its `visible` property to `false` to hide it.

```
//to hide the window
myWindow.visible = false;

//to show it again
myWindow.visible = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why var at the beginning of every line?

try

```
myWindow.close(); 
myWindow.activate();
myWindow.open();
```

or

```
myWindow.close(); 
myWindow = new Window();
myWindow.open();
```